# Can I get exactly opposite result of NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I want "eleven" to 11 and I am not getting the result through::

```
formatter.number(from: "String")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. I cannot reproduce your issue with the following code `let nf = NumberFormatter(); nf.numberStyle = .spellOut; nf.number(from: "eleven")` It produces `11`.

Comment: I have added this line incorrectly :: nf.numberStyle = .spellOut .Now I am able to get the correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.spellOut` style option of `NumberFormatter` works in both ways.

Note that if you want to parse "eleven" you need to set the appropriate Locale:

```
formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US")
```

Then you can reverse the formatting using the same formatter:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
if let number = formatter.number(from: "eleven") {
    print(number) // prints 11
} else {
    // error
}
```